Confusion regarding phase
As far as I know about phase if the phase difference between two waves is positive, the former is leading..and the latter is lagging. Then why has D J Grifith stated this?
If the phase of the magnetic field is ahead of the electric field by $\varphi$, why is he still saying the magnetic field lags?

Yes, your understanding of phase difference is correct: if the phase difference between two waves is positive, the former is leading and the latter is lagging. Let's closely examine what Griffiths is stating in the text and reconcile it with this understanding.
From the provided excerpt, let's analyze the phase relationship:

The complex amplitudes of the electric and magnetic fields are given by:
$$
   \vec{E}(z, t) = \vec{E}_0 e^{-\kappa z} e^{i(kz - \omega t)} \hat{x}
 $$
$$
   \vec{B}(z, t) = \frac{\vec{k}}{\omega} \times \vec{E}_0 e^{-\kappa z} e^{i(kz - \omega t)} \hat{y}
 $$

The wave vector   $\vec{k}  $ is expressed in terms of its modulus and phase:
$$
   \vec{k} = K e^{i\phi}
 $$
where   $ K = |\vec{k}|   $ and   $\phi = \tan^{-1}(\kappa / k)  $.

The relationship between the complex amplitudes of the electric and magnetic fields is:
$$
   B_0 e^{i\delta_B} = \frac{K e^{i\phi}}{\omega} E_0 e^{i\delta_E}
 $$
which simplifies to:
$$
   \delta_B = \delta_E + \phi
 $$
indicating that the phase of the magnetic field   $\delta_B  $ is ahead of the phase of the electric field   $\delta_E  $ by   $\phi  $.


So far, this is consistent with the idea that if   $\delta_B > \delta_E  $, then the magnetic field leads the electric field by   $\phi  $.
However, Griffiths states that "the magnetic field lags behind the electric field." This might initially seem contradictory, but it's important to consider the context and conventions used in electromagnetism. Griffiths is referring to the convention in which the electric field is used as the reference phase (often set to zero for simplicity), and the magnetic field is considered in relation to this reference.
In such a context, saying that the magnetic field lags behind the electric field by   $\phi  $ can be interpreted as follows:
If we take the electric field's phase   $\delta_E  $ to be zero (for reference), the phase of the magnetic field   $\delta_B  $ is   $\phi  $. Since we typically think of lagging in terms of positive phase difference in this specific context (i.e., for the magnetic field to reach the same phase, it would need to "catch up" by   $\phi  $), it might be said to "lag" behind the electric field in a conventional sense.
In other words, despite   $\delta_B = \delta_E + \phi  $ suggesting the magnetic field is ahead, in this context, we are viewing it from the perspective of how much the magnetic field has to "lag" or "delay" to match the reference phase of the electric field, which can lead to this wording.
Thus, Griffiths' statement aligns with the convention of using the electric field's phase as the reference and considering the relative phase of the magnetic field in that context.
Let's put it in a more pragmatic way: if we set the electric field phase to zero and define lagging as a positive phase difference, then everything else should indeed lag behind the electric field in this context.
Let’s clarify and reconcile the terminology used in Griffiths' text with this convention:

Electric Field as Reference: Suppose the phase of the electric field   $\delta_E  $ is taken as the reference, i.e.,   $\delta_E = 0  $.

Magnetic Field Phase: According to the equations given:
$$
   \delta_B = \delta_E + \phi
 $$
Since   $\delta_E = 0  $, this simplifies to:
$$
   \delta_B = \phi
 $$
Thus, the phase of the magnetic field   $\delta_B  $ is   $\phi  $, which is positive.

Interpretation of Phase Difference:

When we say   $\delta_B = \delta_E + \phi  $, it indicates that the magnetic field is ahead of the electric field by   $\phi  $.
Conversely, if we consider lagging in the sense of how much one field would need to "catch up" to be in phase with the other, and if we take the magnetic field phase   $\delta_B  $ as the reference, then the electric field would indeed lag behind the magnetic field by   $-\phi  $. However, we usually do not switch references like this in electromagnetism problems.



In summary, Griffiths' use of the term "lagging" might be unconventional or potentially confusing. Let’s rephrase to be more aligned with standard conventions:

Standard Convention: Positive phase difference usually means leading. So, if   $\delta_B = \phi  $, the magnetic field leads the electric field by   $\phi  $.
Lagging: Using this standard convention, the electric field would lag behind the magnetic field by   $\phi  $ (not typical to state it this way, but for clarity).

To put it simply, the magnetic field leads the electric field by   $\phi  $, which is equivalent to saying the electric field lags behind the magnetic field by   $\phi  $. Griffiths' wording might be a contextual or conventional peculiarity, but it essentially reflects the same phase relationship.
Here is a concise correction in terms of standard terminology:

"The magnetic field leads the electric field by   $\phi  $. Meanwhile, the real amplitudes of   $E  $ and   $B  $ are related by   $\frac{B_0}{E_0} = \frac{K}{\omega} = \sqrt{\epsilon \mu \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon \omega}\right)^2}}  $."

This phrasing aligns with the conventional understanding that a positive phase difference indicates leading.
